# How can I use Android to send PC a message & receive real-time

Tags: c#, android, c++, vb.net, real-time

I have a server & a client. The client is my Android phone. The server is my PC running Windows.

I'm needing to find out the best programmable method of sending a short string to the PC and having it displayed real-time.

Please keep in mind the only languages I can program in on my server-side is VB.NET, C#, and C++ (and my experience with them is in that order).

Edit:
I don't care about security or anything. Both devices will be on a private wifi network. I can't rely on 3rd party applications though, considering the computer running the server will have very little RAM.

Comment: Is this homework, because you could just use something like Skype if not.

Comment: @LajosArpad edited the OP. Not homework but the PC running the server has limited RAM so 3rd party applications aren't a good option for me.

Comment: OK, I will give you an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a .NET project which communicates with sockets. Your PC could listen to a given port and your phone would access that port. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10649/An-Introduction-to-Socket-Programming-in-NET-using) article might help you to learn more about .NET socket programming and you will be able to use C# or Visual Basic as you want.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much! That looks like it has all the info I need :)

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a simple string, and you don't care too much about security or reliability, you could go about this using `java.net.Socket`. Create a `Socket`, giving it your PCs IP address, an open port, etc. Write up an application on the PC to listen to that port, and handle the data as it would. I have no idea how you would go about doing the server-side part, as I've only really used Java, but it shouldn't be that hard if you're going with raw sockets. With the `Socket` on your android, create an output stream, and pass the string through that stream.

If you need a more secure, more reliable, more standard protocol of delivering a string, I'd probably go with HTTP. You might have to read up more about it, but they're better overall. Sockets aren't a whole lot simpler, though.

Comment: I don't care about security or anything. Both devices will be on a private wifi network. HTTP is an option, and I know PHP very well but I don't know if that would be realtime? I'll research using `Socket` but I might need more help if anyone knows how to do the PC part. Thanks!